# nested classes with pointers woth openACC

Tags: gpu, openacc, pgi, pgi-accelerator

I have a rather big code in C++, I had to integrate some new class to the base class as shown below.

```
class A
    {
    int N;
    B  b;
    double *__restrict__ w;
    construct();
    }



  A::construct()
    {
    w=new double[N];

    #pragma acc data enter create(this)
    #pragma acc update device(this)
    #pragma acc data enter create(w)
    // allocate  class A
    b.construct()
    }



  class B
    {
    double *__restrict__ u;
    double *__restrict__ v;
    B(){};
    construct();
    }
    B::construct()
    {
    u=new double[N];
    v=new double[N];
    #pragma acc data enter create(this)
    #pragma acc update device(this)
    #pragma acc data enter create(u)
    #pragma acc data enter create(v)

    }
```

I think I am running into the deep copy issue as the pointers of class B are invalidated and hence the behavior of the code on GPU i undefined. 
I would appreciate the feedback on how to perform the class inclusion in another class without getting into the deep copy issue. I suspect the update device (this) somehow causes this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a full example which recreates the error you're seeing?  I wrote a little test example using your code snip-it and it worked fine. (See below)

If you were updating the "this" pointer after creating the arrays, then it would be a problem since you'd be overwriting the device pointers with the host pointers.  But as you show above, it shouldn't be an issue.

```
% cat test.cpp
#include <iostream>

class B
{
        public:
                int N;
                double *__restrict__ u;
                double *__restrict__ v;
                void construct(int);
};

void B::construct(int _N)
{
        N=_N;
        u=new double[N];
        v=new double[N];
#pragma acc enter data create(this)
#pragma acc update device(this)
#pragma acc enter data create(u[:N])
#pragma acc enter data create(v[:N])
}

class A
{
        public:
                int N;
                B  b;
                double *__restrict__ w;
                void construct(int);
};

void A::construct(int _N)
{
        N=_N;
        w=new double[N];
#pragma acc enter data create(this)
#pragma acc update device(this)
#pragma acc enter data create(w[:N])

        // allocate  class A
        b.construct(N);
}


int main() {

        A myA;
        int N=32;
        myA.construct(N);

#pragma acc parallel loop present(myA)
        for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
                myA.w[i] = i;
                myA.b.u[i] = i;
                myA.b.v[i] = i;
        }
#pragma acc update host( myA.w[:N], myA.b.u[:N], myA.b.v[:N])
        for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
                std::cout << myA.w[i] << ":" << myA.b.u[i] << ":" << myA.b.v[i] << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
% pgc++ test.cpp -Minfo=accel -V18.10 -ta=tesla; a.out
main:
     49, Generating present(myA)
         Accelerator kernel generated
         Generating Tesla code
         52, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(32) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
     56, Generating update self(myA.b.u[:N],myA.w[:N],myA.b.v[:N])
B::construct(int):
     21, Generating update device(this[:1])
         Generating enter data create(this[:1],v[:N],u[:N])
A::construct(int):
     41, Generating update device(this[:1])
         Generating enter data create(w[:N],this[:1])
0:0:0
1:1:1
2:2:2
3:3:3
4:4:4
5:5:5
6:6:6
7:7:7
8:8:8
9:9:9
10:10:10
11:11:11
12:12:12
13:13:13
14:14:14
15:15:15
16:16:16
17:17:17
18:18:18
19:19:19
20:20:20
21:21:21
22:22:22
23:23:23
24:24:24
25:25:25
26:26:26
27:27:27
28:28:28
29:29:29
30:30:30
31:31:31
```

Comment: Sure.  Send it to PGI Customer Service (trs@pgroup,com) and ask Alex to forward it to me.

Comment: Thank you so much as I have been struggling with why this situation arises, as both classes are developed separately and they work fine. when I put them together the issue arises. I just submitted it. Thanks again for your time and help